# How do I stream multiple multipart messages of different mimetypes in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, multipart, http-streaming

I'm currently using Springs `ResponseBodyEmitter` to stream a multipart/related response consisting of multiple parts (of mimetype `application/json` as well as `application/octet-stream`) to a client. Therefore I am manually setting the boundary in the Content-Type header as well as creating the encapsulation boundaries between the different message parts within the payload. I'm pretty sure there is a more convenient way to achieve this. What would be the idiomatic way in Spring to achieve this?

```
@GetMapping(value = "/data", produces = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseBodyEmitter> streamMultipart() {

        // omitting actual contents for the sake of brevity
        InputStream audio = new ByteArrayInputStream(null); //asynchronously retrieved 
        String json = "{}";
        ResponseBodyEmitter speakEmitter = new ResponseBodyEmitter();

        executor.execute(() -> {
            try {
                speakEmitter.send("\r\n--myBoundary\r\n");
                speakEmitter.send("Content-Type: application/json;\r\n\r\n");
                speakEmitter.send(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                speakEmitter.send("\r\n--myBoundary\r\n");
                speakEmitter.send("Content-Type: application/octet-stream;\r\n\r\n");
                speakEmitter.send(audio.readAllBytes(), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
                speakEmitter.send("\r\n--myBoundary--\r\n");
            } catch (IOException ignoredForBrevity) {}
        });

        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "multipart/related; boundary=myBoundary");
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(responseHeaders).body(speakEmitter);
    }
```